# Android Studio - The shared perference can't be saved on the new activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, sharedpreferences

As the question suggested, the shared preference can't be saved on the new activity

```
Set<String> temp = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE).getStringSet("attempt", null);
temp.add("one item");
SharedPreferences editor = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor.edit().putStringSet("attempt", temp).commit();
```

this code work perfectly on the main activity. However, it don't work when I tried to put this code on the another activity.

the edited preference can be view after this code, even after the `destroy();` method of the new activity. However, it is being refreshed to the saved Reference **only with the added item in the main activity before.**

I have been searching for a half hours but I only find question about "Can't save preference" instead of "Can't save preference **only in new activity**"

I am wondering is there any mistake in my code, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your peferences global available I suggest to do a `SharedPrefs.java` class to save your `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
public class SharedPrefs {

public static SharedPreferences prefs(Context context){
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}

//Set your preference
public static void setMyPreference(Context context, String text) {
    prefs(context).edit().putString("MyPreference", text).apply();
}

//Get your preference
public static String getMyPreference(Context context) {
    return prefs(context).getString("MyPreference", "DefaultText");
}
```

And with the following code you can save data from your `Activity` as a `SharedPreference` to your `SharedPrefs.java` class:

```
//To save preferences in SharedPrefs
                String myString = "Hello world";
                SharedPrefs.setMyPreference(getContext(),myString);
```

Or getting it from `SharedPrefs.java` to your `Activity`:

```
//To get preferences from SharedPrefs
                String getMyPreference = SharedPrefs.getCustomString(getContext());
                System.out.println(getCustomString);
                //Result = Hello world
```