# set music volume permanently

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have a background music and there is a button to mute the sound it works fine but even if I mute the sound when I leave the activity and comeback music starts to play again I wanna mute the sound permanently if user doesn't click the sound on button it should stay mute how can I do it.
here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wheel);
    wheelauido=MediaPlayer.create(Wheel.this,R.raw.wheelauido);
    melody.start();
    melody=MediaPlayer.create(Wheel.this,R.raw.melody);
    melody.setLooping(true);
    stopmusic=findViewById(R.id.stopmusic);
    playmusic=findViewById(R.id.playmusic);
       
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    melody.setVolume(0,0);
    stopmusic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    playmusic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void playmusic(View view){
    melody.setVolume(1,1);
    playmusic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    stopmusic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
public void stopmusic(View view){
    melody.setVolume(0,0);
    stopmusic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    playmusic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can save the state as a preference called `SharedPreferences`. Now it will be remembered. The following code shows how to achieve that:

```
public static SharedPreferences prefs(Context context){
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }
    
     
    public static void setMuteButton(Context context, Boolean muted) {
        prefs(context).edit().putBoolean("Mute", muted).apply();
    }
    public static Boolean isMuted(Context context) {
        return prefs(context).getBoolean("Mute", false);
    }
```

In addition I provide you [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68245234/android-studio-the-shared-perference-cant-be-saved-on-the-new-activity/68247682#68247682) I wrote to get more confortable with it.
Happy coding! :)

Comment: Cool, glad to hear! feel free to tick the answer as the correct one in manner of the encyclopedia. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

please do not start on onCreate function.
do it on play function and before start, set volume first.
SharedPreference is good idea.
it can save the data to xml file so the last volume can be load when app restart.

```
private void play(){
    wheelauido=MediaPlayer.create(Wheel.this,R.raw.wheelauido);
    if(isMuted())//use DEX7RA's code.
        melody.setVolume(0,0);
    melody.start();
    melody=MediaPlayer.create(Wheel.this,R.raw.melody);
    melody.setLooping(true);
}
```

Comment: I am glad to hear it.